# Playing a crafting focused character in Dragon Age RPG

Tags: crafting, dragon-age-rpg

I am going to run a DA RPG game using Green Ronin Rule soon for a group of friends.

One of them expressed a desire to play a crafter focus character, an enchanter type like the dwarf guy whose name I temporarily forgot. But I looked through the rules and even some supplements and found nothing of the like. Experts in this system: is this gameplay possible at all, or should I tell my player to try a different concept?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players Guide 2 introduces a the **Crafting (Dexterity)** and **Poison Lore (Cunning)** focuses and the corresponding talents **Trap-Making** and **Poison-Making**, as well as a new background **Ferelden Craftsman**.

Players Guide 3 introduces the **Enchantment (Cunning)** focus and **Runecrafting** talent. Runecrafting is not, however, for making new items - it just allows you to mount runes onto existing weapons and armour.

Gamemasters Guide 3 has the rules for runes, but about their creation it only says, "Skilled dwarven crafstmen and the Tranquil know the secrets of runecraft."

So, unless it was added in the combined books (which I don't have) there is nothing in the rules about playing Sandal Feddic. *Enchantment!*

As an aside, playing an enchanter would probably prove to be really boring.

*GM*: OK, so Alistair and Leliana finish off the fleeing warriors while Morrigan (who disapproves -20) uses the last of her magic to make sure the abomination stays dead. Sandal, what are you doing?

*Player*: Continue working in my lab, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is as I suspect: crafting is a side system to the class system and not a class in itself. Probably I will tell the player to play a relevant and spend talents on crafting.

Just a side note, how do you find the crafting rule in DA RPG if you have had the chance to try it?

Comment: I've only played one session of the game. I bought all 3 sets of rules seperately, never got a game together, and then got grumpy when the money I spent didn't get me a discount on the combined rulebook.

Comment: that  sucks. I hate the 3-book thingy too. Well hope the game will turn out well. Thanks for the help, this answers my question well